# famo.us bug on require LightBox

Tags: javascript, requirejs, lightbox, var, famo.us

I have a problem with famo.us when i make a simple require for LightBox.

```
var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
var Lightbox = require('famous/views/LightBox');

var SlideView = require('views/SlideView');
```

I don't know why but console return this message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8888/slideshow/start/src/famous/views/LightBox.js
```

My question is: why famo.us search on local directory instead search online?

Thanks,
Andrea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequireJS doesn't search online for files. It's merely finding javascript files it's pointed to in `requireConfig`.

RequireJS automatically assumes that each file is a JS file, so the `.js` extensions are left out from the paths when you call `require()`

In this case, all you have is a typo. LightBox should be Lightbox - so rather than looking for `LightBox.js` you should be looking for `Lightbox.js`

ie:

```
var Lightbox = require(`famous/views/Lightbox`);
```

Comment: Oh jesus :)  I had solved yet without realize. Thanks!